# PCL:: CropBox doesn't work, means it doesn't filter the points I want to

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, roi, lidar

I would like to find out what I am doing wrong.

Steps

1. Load .pcd inout file
2. Limit that input file as follow

   ```
   typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloudROI (new pcl::PointCloud<PointT>); 
   pcl::CropBox<PointT> region(true);
   region.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f (-10, -5, -2, 1));
   region.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f (30, 6.5, 1, 1));
   region.setInputCloud(cloud_filtered);
   region.filter(*cloudROI);
   ```

Works fine for me.

But know the next step doesn't work

1. Now I want to filter some points around my Lidar source
2. Therefore I create a second cropbox with the InputCloud from my first segmentation

```
std::vector<int> indices;
pcl::CropBox<PointT> roof(true);
roof.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f (-1.5, -1.7, -1, 1));
roof.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f (2.6, 1.7, -0.4, 1));
roof.setInputCloud(cloudROI);
region.filter(indices);

pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers {new pcl::PointIndices};
for (int point : indices)
{
 inliers->indices.push_back(point);
  std::cout << "Found inliers" << std::endl;
}

pcl::ExtractIndices<PointT> extract;
extract.setInputCloud(cloudROI);
extract.setIndices(inliers);
extract.setNegative(true);
extract.filter(*cloudROI);
```

If I simulate my code I get the following result.

[image: First picture is without filtering the roof points around my Lidar]

[image: Result, with second cropbox]

As you can see, the filter cropped points from the plane on the right side, although my box is never that big. Also keeps the one in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple bug, just replace the code from `region.filter(indices)`
to `roof.filter(indices)`, the other part looks good

```cpp
pcl::CropBox<PointT> roof(true);
roof.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f (-1.5, -1.7, -1, 1));
roof.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f (2.6, 1.7, -0.4, 1));
roof.setInputCloud(cloudROI);
region.filter(indices); // <-------
```

You were having issue because the `inliers` is the result of `region` cropbox with respect to the `cloud_filtered`. However, you extract the negative indices of the `inliers` with respect to the `cloudROI` indices, that's why you received the point that you're not expecting